# StateFlow fetching the same data again on Back Navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

I am working with **RecyclerView** and using **Retrofit** to fetch the data from Server. I am using **Kotlin** with **MVVM** Design Pattern. I have used **LiveData** it was working fine. But with Stateflow causing issues when we navigate to another Fragment and Comes back to the Same Fragment again. It just fetches the same data again. Below is the code for ViewModel and the observer:

//View Model

```
private val _allTimeSheetsResponse =
        MutableStateFlow<ResponsesResult<AllTimeSheetsResponse>>(ResponsesResult.Empty)
    val allTimeSheetsResponse : StateFlow<ResponsesResult<AllTimeSheetsResponse>> get() = _allTimeSheetsResponse

    fun getAllTimeSheets(auth: String) =
        viewModelScope.launch {
            timeSheetsRepository.getAllTimeSheets(auth).collect {
                _allTimeSheetsResponse.value = it
            }
        }
```

//Observer

```
lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted{
            timeSheetsViewModel.allTimeSheetsResponse.collect { timeSheetsResponse ->
                when (timeSheetsResponse) {
                    is ResponsesResult.Loading -> binding.progressBarLayout.show()
                    is ResponsesResult.Failure -> {
                        binding.progressBarLayout.gone()
                        binding.nothingFoundLayout.show()
                        handleApiError(timeSheetsResponse)
                    }
                    is ResponsesResult.Success -> {
                        binding.progressBarLayout.gone()
                        if (timeSheetsResponse.value.payload.isNotEmpty()) {
                            showAllTimeSheetsRecyclerAdapter.submitList(timeSheetsResponse.value.payload)
                        } else {
                            binding.nothingFoundLayout.show()
                        }
                    }
                    else -> Unit
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you call `getAllTimeSheets` many times (eg. `onCreateView or` onViewCreated`). Trying call it when accessing` allTimeSheetsResponse` for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Your ViewModel's `getAllTimeSheets()` function starts a new coroutine to collect from the repo's cold Flow each time you call it, so each time the Fragment comes back, presumably. You should remove this function and simply convert the repo's cold Flow directly to a StateFlow:

```
val allTimeSheetsResponse: StateFlow<ResponsesResult<AllTimeSheetsResponse>> = 
    timeSheetsRepository.getAllTimeSheets(auth)
        .stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.Eagerly, ResponsesResult.Empty)
```

You can pass the `auth` parameter into the ViewModel's factory through to its constructor.

Comment: How am I supposed to call a **suspend** function without a **Coroutines Scope**? More Specifically how should I use the line of code you provided? Should I replace all of the **ViewModels** code with the code you provided or is it needs to be attached with the existing code?

Comment: Where is there a suspend function being called in my code?  It’s just a property declaration.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the navigationComponent and call `navController.navigate()` to open a fragment, in the background destination fragment replaces with the old destination's fragment. so old fragment will keep in the fragmentManager backStack. but its view will destroy. and when navigate back, old fragment comes from backStack (not created again) and just its view creates.

So it's better to call `getAllTimeSheets()` in Fragment's `onCreate`. (to call one time). When fetching done, all data will set in `_allTimeSheetsResponse`

And then you should observe `allTimeSheetsResponse` in `onViewCreated` with `viewLifecycleOwner` scope.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    viewModel.allTimeSheetsResponse.onEach { response ->

        // do sth with response

    }.launchIn(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
    fun getAllTimeSheets(auth: String) :StateFlow<ResponsesResult<AllTimeSheetsResponse>> {
        var mutableStateFlow = MutableStateFlow<ResponsesResult<AllTimeSheetsResponse>>(ResponsesResult.Empty)
        viewModelScope.launch {
            timeSheetsRepository.getAllTimeSheets(auth).collect {
                mutableStateFlow.value = it
            }
        }

        return mutableStateFlow
    }
```